# SQL Server 2008 express performance in production environment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I am about to move servers and i was talking to somebody and they suggested using sql server express 2008 installed on the servers. I have full access to the server.

Does this express engine work at the same speed (performance) as a true sql server 2008?

I know about the limitations i..e max 4 GB per DB ... and max 1 GB of ram... Considering the server has 2GB installed and is shared with windows... i don't see this being a problem but would love to hear some feedback..

I have around 4 dbs .. and they have maybe 4 users logged into them at the same time, its not a great deal of use really...

What i really trying to mesure up is if i should installed SQL SERVER 2008 FULL version on the server or express..

Any help with a choice would be really helpful.

It appears express uses the same DB engine as the FULL version ...

I don't need any clever replication, clustering or things like that...

But i want to go down the right path ...

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express is the same code as the other SQL editions (Workgroup, Standard, Enterprise/Developer and Data Center). The only different code base is the 'CE' edition, that is based on the mobile SQL CE code. Express has the restrictions you already enumerated (DB size, RAM) and also is using only one scheduler, so in effect will use only one CPU core. Also certain features are restricted in Express, like certain replication scenarios. The biggest advantage is that customers can start with Express and if they out-grow its capabilities they can swap in a higher edition without any application change, the database files are interchangeable between all editions, including Express.

Comment: "also is using only one scheduler, so in effect will use only one CPU core" -- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/06/10/sql-server-2008-express-rc0.aspx "SQL Express will take advantage of multiple cores on the single CPU by starting a scheduler for each core."

Answer (score 3):

Its the same engine, but I found you have to fight it all the way in making it anything but a desktop-environment database, from management to tcpip configuration, etc. And of course, it has built in limits on database size and resource usage. Once it is configured the way you want though, it runs fine. In real production settings I find the lack of SSIS quite the killer, though.

So the bottom line is that it is usable, but not great. You might also consider the Workgroup edition, which is reasonably priced and less limited, but of course it is more expensive than free.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to this SQL Express 2008 R2 can use multiple cores (but only 1 CPU).

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be fine with Express.  It's the same basic engine.  If you ever want to upgrade, the process should be rather painless.

Comment: thanks .. but do you know the difference in performance ?? considering i am installing it on the same server as IIS (web server) with 2GB of ram?

Comment: The difference in performance will only come if you are running into memory limits or things like indexed views (which aren't available).  You would have to give more information about your workload to see if you would actually benefit from paralelism or any of the other advanced features.  1 users on a 2GB database with bad indexes is a probably lot poorer than 1000 users on a well-designed 50MB database.

Answer (score 0):

you should be fine, performance should be similar to full version in your case since your databases are small